# Rotate Angular - chevron - on click

Tags: css, angular, typescript

I am trying to rotate the chevron-left to chevron-right whenever they are clicked but with animation in Angular .

CSS:

```
.rotate-chevron {
    transition: .1s linear;
  }
```

HTML:

```
<button   [class.button-open]="!slideOpen"
          [class.button-close]="slideOpen"
          (click)="changeSlide()">
    <i class="rotate">{{slideOpen ? 'chevron_left' : 'chevron_right'}}</i>
  </button>
```

TS:

```
changeSlide(): void {
    this.slideOpen = !this.slideOpen;
  }
```

Here is a sample [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KYZeqJ?html-preprocessor=none)

Comment: whats the issue you are facing? I have tried it in Angular, its working perfectly

Comment: @AbdulBasit can you share the code where it is working please. So the issue above is I am trying to achieve it in Angular where as I am able to write in jQuery but unable to replicate the same in Angular

Comment: please check my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the working [link](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gyojJY)

**.TS**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.css">
<button   [class.button-open]="!slideOpen"
          [class.button-close]="slideOpen"
          (click)="changeSlide()">
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" [class.clicked]="slideOpen"></i>
  </button>`
})
class AppComponent {  
    slideOpen: any = false;

  title="hello world angular 6";
  constructor() {
    // TODO: Define your Angular component implementation
  }
    changeSlide(): void {
    this.slideOpen = !this.slideOpen;
  }
}
```

**CSS**

```
.fa {
    transition: all .5s linear;
}
.clicked {
    transform:rotate(180deg);
}
```

Comment: Very close @abdul but this is rotating only in one direction, either to right in both clicks or to left if changed to [class.clicked]="!slideOpen"

Comment: Also, I want it to be like <i class="rotate">{{slideOpen ? 'chevron_left' : 'chevron_right'}}</i>

Comment: Thank you @Abdul for your efforts

Comment: @Bob anytime bro

Answer (score 1):

since you're using icons from cdn, you can't simply animate them. What you can do is use only one svg and rotate it with css transform. Example:

html:

```
<button   [class.button-open]="!slideOpen"
          [class.button-close]="slideOpen"
          (click)="changeSlide()">
    <i class="rotate" [ngStyle]="getChevronStyle()>;"> chevron_left </i>
  </button>
```

js:

```
getChevronStyle(){
    if(this.slideOpen) {
        return { 'transform': 'rotate(0deg)' }
    } else {
        return { 'transform': 'rotate(180deg)' }
    }
}
```

css:

```
.rotate {
    transition: all .1s linear;
  }
```

You can check css transform compatibility here: https://caniuse.com/#search=transform
Also you can check more info about ngStyle here: https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle
Hope it helps!

Comment: Here I get: Cannot set property 'transform' of undefined

Comment: Thank you @Gabriel for your efforts