# In angular 11, how can you make a caret rotate conditionally?

Tags: angular, rotation, font-awesome, caret

I've tried everything imaginable. I need the caret to rotate when showNavDropdownDashboard is either true or false, doesn't matter at the moment. The only time I ever got the caret to rotate is when I set transform="rotate-180-deg", nothing else works...

Setting rotate="90" fails because "TS2322: Type '"90"' is not assignable to type '90 | 180 | 270 | undefined'."

Using ngClass fails, I never see the class assigned... ive tried every equivalent format i can find, its getting ridiculous.

```
<div type="button" (click)="collapse.toggle()">
    <fa-icon [icon]="caret"></fa-icon>
</div>
<div #collapse="ngbCollapse" [(ngbCollapse)]="!showNavTop">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" (click)="showNavDropdownDashboard = !showNavDropdownDashboard">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="navbar-collapse" [class.collapse]="!showNavDropdownDashboard">
            <ul ngbNav class="navbar-nav">
                <li ngbDropdown>
                    <div ngbNavLink ngbDropdownToggle>
                        linkies
                    </div>
                    <div ngbDropdownMenu class="dropdown-menu-dark">
                        <button ngbDropdownItem>- 1 Demo</button>
                        <button ngbDropdownItem>- 2 Demo</button>
                        <button ngbDropdownItem>+ New Dashboard</button>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

class

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { faCaretUp } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-nav-top',
  templateUrl: './nav-top.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./nav-top.component.css']
})
export class NavTopComponent implements OnInit {
  caret = faCaretUp;
  constructor() { }

  public showNavDropdownDashboard = false;
  public showNavTop = false;
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```

css

```
.transform-turn-0 {
    transform:rotate(-0deg);
    transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out; /*for smoothness*/
}
.transform-turn-180 {
    transform:rotate(-180deg);
    transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out; /*for smoothness*/
}
```

angular version

```
Angular CLI: 11.2.5
Node: 15.11.0
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 11.2.6
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... localize, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1102.5
@angular-devkit/build-angular   0.1102.5
@angular-devkit/core            11.2.5
@angular-devkit/schematics      11.2.5
@angular/cli                    11.2.5
@schematics/angular             11.2.5
@schematics/update              0.1102.5
rxjs                            6.6.6
typescript                      4.1.5
```

Comment: You could check this answer out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55715705/rotate-angular-chevron-on-click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
<fa-icon [icon]="caret" [rotate]="90"></fa-icon>
```

This approach resolved the problem for me.

Unfortunately I am still mostly a beginner at TypeScript and Angular so I cannot explain with confidence why this works. I had the same problem and I came across your post looking for an answer. Perhaps a more knowledgeable TypeScript/Angular developer can explain.

I suspect it something along the lines of:

`rotate="90"` is seen as normal property assignment and so the value "90" is a string. TypeScript expects rotate to be numeric (90 or 180 or 270 or undefined)

`[rotate]="90"` the value inside the "" is seen as TypeScript code. The value "90" is seen as numeric and TypeScript is happy everything is valid.

As for your second requirement that rotation only happens when `showNavDropdownDashboard === true` you can take advantage of the TypeScript execution in the property assignment e.g.

```
 <fa-icon [icon]="caret" [rotate]="showNavDropdownDashboard === true ? 90 : undefined"></fa-icon>
```

Comment: Thanks. I've come to realize that my difficulties were related to ngb, a ridiculous wrapper angular puts around bootstrap to make it fit within their own paradigm... thus restricting the many different ways bootstrap allows this to work and not documenting it effectively.